# Apache Spark on EC2 massive slowdown on iterations

Tags: amazon-ec2, apache-spark

I have driver program that runs a set of 5 experiments - basically the driver program just tells the program which dataset to use (of which there are 5 and they're very similar).

The first iteration takes 3.5 minutes, the second 6 minutes, the third 30 minutes and the fourth has been running for over 30 minutes.

After each run the `SparkContext` object is stopped, it is then re-started for the next run - I thought this method would prevent slow down, as when `sc.stop` is called I was under the impression that the instances were cleared of all their RDD data - this is at least how it works in local mode. The dataset is quite small and according to Spark UI only 20Mb of data on 2 nodes is used.

Does `sc.stop` not remove all data from a node? What would cause such a slow down?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stupidly, I had used T2 instances. Their burstable performance means they only work on full power for a small amount of time. Read the documentation thoroughly - lesson learnt!

Answer (score 0):

1. call `sc.stop` after all iterations are complete. Whenever we stop SparkContenxt and invoke new, it require time to load spark configurations,jars and free driver port to execute the next job. 
   and
2. using config `--executor-memory` you can speed up the process, depending on how much memory you have in each node.

Comment: I called `sc.stop` after all iterations and it just got slower even quicker. I'm guessing because each iteration created shuffle files that never got deleted? Each node has 1Gb memory for this particular question.

Comment: I think If you have memory more than 1 GB in each node then you should apply --executor-memory to Xg > 1g, where Xg should be available memory in each node before you hit spark-submit

Comment: I am utilising the full memory of each instance and also after each run of the programming calling `sc. stop`. It keeps happening. I run the context cleaner - it doesn't help. I have to launch a new cluster every time I want to run an iteration else it's too slow.